# why the "${}" tag in jsp output as a string

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to import a js file in my jsp like this way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/layout/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

but when i browse the deployed page ,i found the `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`part are showed on the browsers as a string,the code above try to find js file in the `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/layout/` folder instead of`XXX/js/layout/`

My developing environment is "Myeclipse10.5+Tomcat7.0+JDK7.0"

Comment: Does the page contain other EL expressions that are not evaluated properly?

Comment: all the EL expressions on this page are not evaluated properly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your JSP isn't configured to ignore EL with a `page` directive

```
<%@ page ... isELIgnored="true" %>
```

Or, check that your `web.xml` hasn't turned EL off for all JSPs with

```
<jsp-config>
  ...
  <el-ignored>true</el-ignored>
  ...
</jsp-config>
```

***EDIT*** :

Also, check that your `web.xml`'s `<web-app>` version is `2.4` or higher. Add the following to your `web.xml` as a workaround *(if nothing else works)* :

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: no..actually it works well until I change my computer and rebuild my workspace last week....

Comment: just the path error  `127.0.0.1 - - [26/Aug/2013:12:35:01 +0800] "GET /$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/js/jquery.top.method.js HTTP/1.1" 404 180`

Comment: I add `isELIgnored="false"` on the page and it works....but i still can't find where I disable it....

Comment: Check your `web.xml`'s `<web-app>` version. It should be `2.4`.

Comment: here's my web.xml head `<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" 
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 >`

Answer (score 0):

This is part of Java EL (Expression Language)

Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html as to how it works.